# How to postpone <head> rendering?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have the layout like this:

```
@@ layouts/v2.html.ep
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    %= content_for 'stylesheets'
  </head>
<body>
  %= include 'layouts/v2/header'
  <main class="main">
    %= include 'layouts/v2/menu'
    <div class="content">
    %= content
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>


@@ layouts/v2/menu
% content_for stylesheets => begin
  %= stylesheet 'v2/css/menu.css'
% end
<aside class="menu">
  ...
</aside>

@@ layouts/v2/header
% content_for stylesheets => begin
  %= stylesheet 'v2/css/header.css'
% end
<header class="header">
  ...
</header>
```

Here when templates are included I include their style sheets.
Notice this in template:

```
% content_for stylesheets => begin
  %= stylesheet 'v2/css/menu.css'
% end
```

But this is too late to do that, because the `<head>` is already rendered.

As workaround this problem I can move `%= content_for 'stylesheets'` from `<head>` to the bottom of page. But I want style sheets are loaded first.

**Is there any way to postpone rendering for the content of 'stylesheets' block until whole page is rendered?**

**UPD**

Thank to @amon about that `Mojolicous layouts are rendered inside out`. I understand the problem and there for templates included from first `layout` I include stylesheets manually:

```
@@ layouts/v2.html.ep
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    %= stylesheet 'v2/css/header.css'
    %= stylesheet 'v2/css/menu.css'
    %= content_for 'stylesheets'
  </head>
<body>
  %= include 'layouts/v2/header'
  <main class="main">
    %= include 'layouts/v2/menu'
    <div class="content">
    %= content
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

So in any rendered/included template (except layout) next works fine:

```
@@ some/template
% content_for stylesheets => begin
  %= stylesheet 'some/template.css'
% end
template content
```

Comment: The approach you'd use with TT: `some_page.tt`: `[% stylesheet = ... %][% WRAPPER wrapper.tt %]...[% END %]` and `wrapper.tt`: `<head>[% stylesheet %]</head>[% content %]`. Does Mojolicious have some kind of wrapper directive?

Comment: @ikegami: Seems it is `layout` helper command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mojolicous layouts are rendered inside-out, and you can nest arbitrarily many layouts.

Create a template that includes just the outermost document content and other HTML boilerplate, with a placeholder for the content of `<body>`

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    %= content_for 'stylesheets'
  </head>
  <body>
    %= content
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you can use that template as the layout for the body of your HTML page. I.e., use the `layout` helper like this:

```
% layout 'outermost_layout';
%= include 'layouts/v2/header'
<main class="main">
  %= include 'layouts/v2/menu'
  <div class="content">
  %= content
  </div>
</main>
```

After rendering the template, Mojolicious will check whether you specified a `layout` and then render it, using the output from this template as the outer layout's `content`. So because the innermost layout is rendered first, data can flow from your templates through the stash to wrapping layouts.

Comment: With your help I understand the problem I have

Comment: @amon: *"This allows data to flow from inner templates to outer layouts"* I'm unsure that that's either true or relevant

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for your style improvements (I'll come back later to edit relevant technical terms back in). I think mentioning the data flow is very relevant because that's at the core of the question: the data cannot flow back in time to where a block was already rendered, but it can flow to an outer layout.

Comment: @amon: You're welcome, but I don't think *data flow* is any more relevant to *Mojolicious* templates than it is to Perl subroutines, where you would never think to emphasise the concept.