# How can I access the current template name in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'd like to access the template name in Mojolicious *from inside the template itself* for debugging purposes, in the same way the Template Toolkit does (see [here](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_template))

The variable `__FILE__` works neatly but it refers to the *current* file and not to the top level template, which means it's useless inside a layout template.

I've also tried

```
<%= app->renderer->template_name %>
```

but no result

Is it possible at all in Mojolicious?

Comment: In https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mojolicious/f1SLFXSGRVk sri suggests to use `<%= __FILE__ %>`.

Comment: @simbabque it does not work if used in a wrapper template (layout) - see the question

Comment: Sri also calls doing this a code smell in the thread. It seems they haven't implemented anything that allows you to do it by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in two slightly different ways:

First by adding a `before_render` hook and setting a variable. It's easy to pack it all inside a plugin like so:

```
package Mojolicious::Plugin::TemplateName;

use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Plugin';

sub register {
    my ($self, $app, $conf) = @_;

    $app->helper('template' => sub { return shift->stash('mojo.template') });
    $app->hook(before_render => sub {
           my $c = shift;
           $c->stash('mojo.template', $_[0]->{template} )
           });
}

1;
```

and use it inside a template like this

```
<%= template %>
```

Second, it can be done inside the templates - by setting the variable inside the template itself:

```
% stash('template', __FILE__);
```

and then reusing the variable in the layout:

```
<%= $template %>
```

In this case you get the file name with suffix and all - not just the template.

Inspired by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798400/how-to-postpone-head-rendering/47798601#47798601) about templates being rendered inside-out.